# Python3 error No module named 'attrs' when running Scrapy in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I am new to Python. I installed Scrapy on ubuntu linux. When I run `Scrapy shell` I get this error

```
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/retry.py", line 25, in <module>
from twisted.web.client import ResponseFailed
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 24, in <module>
from twisted.internet.endpoints import HostnameEndpoint, wrapClientTLS
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py", line 63, in <module>
from twisted.python.systemd import ListenFDs
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twisted/python/systemd.py", line 18, in <module>
from attrs import Factory, define
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'attrs'
```

I also already ran the commands

```
python3.10 -m pip install attrs
pip install attrs
```

with the result

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
> Requirement already satisfied: attrs in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (21.2.0)

Comment: having the same issue on MacOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

few days ago i was also facing same issue while trying to run my scraper spider on linux server then i figured it out by running my scrapy spider inside an virtual environment. Hopefully it will also work for you.:)

Comment: what are the details of your virtual environment?

Comment: It was basically scraper built with scrapy . So inside my virtual environment there was only scrapy installed.

Answer (score 3):

For me what worked was to uninstall scrapy and attrs (`pip uninstall scrapy attrs`) and reinstalling scrapy. I didn't have to re-install attrs because scrapy ships with it's own version of attrs.

Answer (score 1):

First, I solved this by uninstalling attrs with the following command:

```
pip uninstall scrapy attrs
```

Then I re-install scrapy with this command `pip3 install scrapy`.

This is what worked for me